# Sending a result array from php using java to populate a table

Tags: java, php, android

I want to populate my table layout in Android XML from a MySQL database using PHP.

I have queried the database with the PHP and I am able to pass Strings from the PHP file to my Java. How do I pass the whole result array to populate my table?

```
public TransactionLogConnection(String vuname, String vpword)
{
    vendorusername = vuname;
    vendorpassword = vpword;
}

public String dbresult()
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://cediline.com/TransactionLog.php");  
    String text;

    try {
        List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vendor_username", vendorusername));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vendor_password", vendorpassword));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

        int current = 0;

        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
            baf.append((byte)current);
        }  

        text = new String(baf.toByteArray());
        return text;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

private class Load_Log extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        String username;
        String password;

        public Load_Log(String uname, String pword)
        {
            username = uname;
            password = pword;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            TransactionLogConnection con = new TransactionLogConnection(username,password);
            return con.dbresult().replace("\n", "");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            shout("Updating...");
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            for(int count = 0; count<=2; ++count)
            {
                newtext.setText(result);
                newRow.addView(newtext); 
            }

            newtext.setText(result);
            newRow.addView(newtext); 

            tbl.addView(newRow);
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

enter code here
$vendor_username = $_POST["vendor_username"];
$vendor_password = $_POST["vendor_password"];

```
$sql="select phonenumber from confidential_detail where username = '$vendor_username' and password = '$vendor_password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result)
{
    echo "error:unable to load log";
}
else
    {
    $phonenumber = mysql_result($result, 0);
    $sql="select amount, date, creditor_phone_number from voucher_records where debitor_phone_number = '$phonenumber'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result)
    {
        return $result;


    }
    else
    {
        echo "error:unable to load log";
    }

    //return $balance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not shared your php code, but the way it works , you will encode PHP array into JSON data, then your app will be able to parse the json string into java objects.

Some helpful pointers:

Read up about JSON:

- http://www.json.org/java/

Some JSON libraries:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html
- https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

PHP

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

**PHP CODE**

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Unable to get log: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo json_encode($row);
```